# PHP GD : black goes transparent

Tags: php, gd, alpha-transparency

On my website, users can upload 3 images with any ratio, and I want to create an animated GIF with 3 thumbnails.
Because the ratio can be different, the animated GIF must have :

- X width : max of any of the 3 images width
- Y height: max of any of the 3 images height

So I create 3 thumbnails of max_width x max_height with transparent background then center its reduced image inside.

My concern is that the deep black goes transparent:

[image]

Here is the code inspired by one of Mihai Iorga's answer:

```
  foreach ($jpg_files as $key => $photo) {
     // Identification de largeur et hauteur max des vignettes, pour centrage ultérieur
     $thumb_w = $w_array[$key];
     $thumb_h = $h_array[$key];
     list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($photo);

     if($thumb_w> $thumb_h) {
        $off_y=ceil(($max_thumb_h-$thumb_h)/2);
        $off_x=0;
     } elseif($thumb_h> $thumb_w) {
        $off_x=ceil(($max_thumb_w-$thumb_w)/2);
        $off_y=0;
     }
     else {
        $off_x=$off_y=0;
     }

     // Création des vignettes GIF centrées sur fond transparent
     $src = "";
     $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
     $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_thumb_w, $max_thumb_h);
     imagealphablending($new_img, false);
     imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
     imagecopyresampled($new_img, $src, $off_x, $off_y, 0, 0, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, $w_orig, $h_orig);

     // create a new image with max size
     $maxsize = imagecreatetruecolor($max_thumb_w, $max_thumb_h);

     // add 1x1 gif and resize, then copy over $maxsize
     $background = imagecreatefromgif('images/1pix_transparent.gif'); // transparent 1x1 gif
     imagecopyresampled($maxsize, $background, 0, 0, 0, 0, $max_thumb_w, $max_thumb_h, 1, 1);

     // allocate transparency
     $transparent = imagecolortransparent($maxsize);
     $transparent_index = imagecolorallocate($maxsize, $transparent['red'], $transparent['green'], $transparent['blue']);
     imagecolortransparent($maxsize, $transparent_index);

     // image copy
     //imagecopymerge($maxsize, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $max_thumb_w, $max_thumb_h, 100);
     imagecopy($maxsize, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $max_thumb_w, $max_thumb_h);

     // save
     imagegif($maxsize, $uploadDir.'/thumb_'.$NewFileNameNoExt.$key.'.gif');

     // destroy temp images
     imagedestroy($maxsize);
     imagedestroy($new_img);
     imagedestroy($background);
     imagedestroy($src);  

     array_push($gif_array, $uploadDir.'/thumb_'.$NewFileNameNoExt.$key.'.gif');
     $framed[$key] = 150;
  }

  $thumbName = $uploadDir.'/thumb_'.$NewFileNameLeft.'.gif';
  include "includes/GIFEncoder.class.php";
  $gif = new GIFEncoder($gif_array, $framed, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, "url");
  fwrite(fopen($thumbName, "wb"),$gif->GetAnimation());
```